# git clone fails with "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: gcc, git, gnu

While trying to git clone the RISC-V GNU toolchain Github project, it is showing following errors. I don't have any idea how to get rid of them.

```
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu.git' into submodule path 'riscv-qemu' failed
```

Here is the link of the toolchain project:
https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain

Comment: Several answers here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977206/fatal-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: You might find this informative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) the remote server dropped your connection for some reason. This could be caused by a number of reasons as mentioned by valiano in referring to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977206/fatal-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer) A quick review of the link you mentioned indicates that the submodule path that you aren't getting to can be accessed [here](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu/tree/ff36f2f77ec3e6a6211c63bfe1707ec057b12f7d) as a workaround.

Sources linked in the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977206/fatal-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer

https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu/tree/ff36f2f77ec3e6a6211c63bfe1707ec057b12f7d